# Is it possible to load annotations from file in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress, kustomize

I have a very long configuration for `nginx ingress` that I have to specify using `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet` annotation.

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: |
      gzip            on;
      gzip_types      text/plain application/xml text/css application/javascript;
      gzip_min_length 1000;
      ... about 100 more lines ...
```

It is a little ugly to mix resource definition files with nginx configuration, and also some configurations are shared among multiple ingresses. So I want to know, is there any way to load the configuration from a file? I'm using `kustomize`.

Comment: Are you using a helm chart?

Comment: No, just deploying definitions built with `kustomize` (using `flux` actually).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you are looking for a way to put your server-snippet configuration into a file and load it into your ingresses.

---

From what I see in the [documentation](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/configmap/#server-snippet), it's possible to create a configmap with a server-snippet configuration, and load it into your ingress.

There is an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55279030/11977760) of such configuration.

---

If you would use Helm:

- According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65291822/11977760) you can create a configmap from a file.
- I also found an  [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65034216/11977760) with server-snippet as multiline environment variable.

Comment: As the documentations says, using configmaps will inject the config in ALL server sections in the ingress, and it means all namespaces and applications. I suppose this is rarely wanted and won't be useful in my case.

Comment: u need to configure your configmap file  check it first # kubectl get cm - A and edit your ingress controller configmap